# Accessing variables from a parent class when using an instance of the child does not seem to be working

Tags: java, scala, apache-kafka

I'm trying to port a program in Java over to Scala, however, I'm running into an error.

I have a line that accesses `DistributedConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG`.

In Java, this works fine.

However, in Scala this gives the error

`value BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG is not a member of org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedConfig`

Looking into the `DistributedConfig` class, `BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG` is actually not defined in the class, but defined in `WorkerConfig` which `DistributedConfig` extends. I've checked and the variable is public. `public static final String BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG` is the exact definition.

Comment: What if you change it to `WorkerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVER_CONFIG`?

Comment: Whoops, sorry yeah it should be BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG everywhere. Just double checked in the code, no spelling errors, I just misspelled it in the post.

Comment: Do not ever retype code or error messages -- ALWAYS copy/paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java "fakes" inheritance of static members (when you write `DistributedConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG`, the Java compiler turns it into `WorkerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG`), Scala doesn't because it wouldn't fit with Scala's approach to statics (using companion objects). So in Scala you can only use `WorkerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG`.